# asp-append='true' adding some random value to type in script tag in asp dotnet core 3.1

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, windows-server

When am adding **asp-append-version="true"** then it's generating type with some random number in live server. In my local system it's  working well, no such thing is generating.

Any help for this please

```
<script src="~/js/view/SignalrFunctions.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

and output in live is

```
<script src="/js/view/SignalrFunctions.js?v=r6rspvdRJxE77iwZz4pxl9MBcr2z6gL1ckobKWF3rts" type="2707b0341fc8574517d57e9b-text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Please include before and after.

Comment: @Llama can you explain more please ?

Comment: Well, where are you adding `asp-append-version="true"`? There's no example in your question.

Comment: @Llama i have updated my question. Now check please.

Comment: If you manually add `type="text/javascript"` to your declaration, does it still do this?

Comment: @Llama if am adding manually then it's w3c validator showing warning for this. That's why i have removed type from script tag.

Answer (score 0):

We normally use static files like CSS, Image and JS files to our website to make it interactive and dynamic. But when we update any file like css, js or image then we need to tell the browser to take the latest file, not the oldest one. But we really don't want user to do full refresh each and every time when we change/update css, js or image file. And asp-append-version="true" is to help us solve this problem.

So this additional attribute helps us to tell the browser to always use updated content whether it is for CSS, JS or any Image file. The random string that appears just tells the browser to use the updated file.

Comment: It's not random, it's a hash of the file contents.

Comment: @ding-peng I know how asp-append-version="true" works but problem is that it's generating `type="2707b0341fc8574517d57e9b-text/javascript"` which is not a valid value for type.

Comment: According to the explanation in the Microsoft documentation, asp-append-version="true" does not generate type. So I think this may not be caused by asp-append-version="true": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/image-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0